# How to get acknowledgement from consumer to broker in kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a consumer that gets message from broker, i want to perform some task when consumer receives a message and when a particular task ends consumer gets another message.

```
 public class Consumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);
    @KafkaListener(topics = "gst", groupId = "group-1")
    public void consumeGst(String message){
            logger.info(String.format("$$ -> Consumed GST Message -> %s",message));

    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "pf", groupId = "group-2")
    public void consumePf(String pfmessage) {
        logger.info(String.format("$$ -> ===============> Consumed Pf Message -> %s", pfmessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippet showing how you are consuming messages. It will make things easy to help.

Comment: currently i am printing the message, i want to know if there is any manual trigger for acknowledgement from consumer to broker

Comment: are you looking for manual acknowledgement @LokeshKumarMeena ?

Comment: Yes, Acknowledgement From Consumer to Broker

Comment: Are you talking about manual commit? https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-kafka-dist/1.1.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#committing-offsets